# WPF: Show window while DataGrid sorting data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcolumnheader

Is it possible to open window with progressbar when client click on datagridcolumnheader?
I have lot of datagrids, so it would be one method for whole dg's, so i created method :

```
namespace myApp
{
    partial class ColumnClick 
    {
        void columnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Colum Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

And in resource file:

```
x:Class="myApp.ColumnClick"
```

plus

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
        <EventSetter Event="DataGridColumnHeader.Click" Handler="columnHeader_Click"></EventSetter>
    </Style>
```

But im still getting error like:

```
'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '21'.
```

Error point line "x:Class="myApp.ColumnClick" in Resources.xaml.

Thanks for help!

Comment: why do you want to create a Window?
Just make an overlay Canvas with a Progressbar create a Property IsBusy and Bind the Visibility of the Canvas with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter to this Property!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [BusyControl](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home) from WPF Extended Toolkit.